# How can I validate a pdf's digital signature with evince?

Tags: 12.10, evince, signature

A while ago I received a PDF file that was digitally signed.

The Document Viewer (Evince) shows me that the digital signature was not validated.

How do I add the file's digital signature to evince so that the warning disappears?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, [you can't](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=614929) (now on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/143)) do this at the minute with the standard version of `evince`, as a developer explained on the [official mailing lists](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2011-April/msg00010.html):

> This feature isn't implemented in Evince, mainly because isn't supported
> by poppler, the underlying library for PDF support.

This is indeed the main point; you would need to patch `poppler` with the digital signature support as well as `evince`.

However, there is a [interesting project](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2012-August/msg00008.html) in progress to provide just the functionality you want; the details are explained on this [github page](https://github.com/diaz/evince-signatures) entitled 'evince signatures', where all the patches are available.

As well as on the github page, there is more information on the project [on this site](http://contribsoft.caixamagica.pt/trac/wiki/PDFSign); it is clear they hope to integrate it upstream in the future. The developers note that

> the most used software for reading pdf documents on Windows (Acrobat Reader) has support for showing and validate signatures in pdf documents. On modern Linux desktops that doesn't yet exist and that's the purpose of this project, change Evince document viewer (default gnome pdf reader) to add those features.

So, you can experiment with the github development code if you wish, but it may not be a good idea to patch `poppler` as other programs depend on it; however, it is likely that the digital signatures feature will be available soon if it is integrated upstream. Judging by the `evince` screenshots [for a valid](http://contribsoft.caixamagica.pt/trac/browser/internals/2012/pdfsign/final/screenshots/valid.png) and [invalid](http://contribsoft.caixamagica.pt/trac/browser/internals/2012/pdfsign/final/screenshots/multiple-invalid.png) signature the patches do seem to be enabling just the features you are interested in.

Comment: How come this is not yet possible? Or is it?

Comment: I would also like to know is this possible now in 2017.?

Comment: didn't find it in `evince`, but at least there is command-line `pdfsig(1)` from `poppler-utils` package that can perform .pdf signature validation

Comment: 9 years has passed -- and this is still not possible. :-(