# How to check if PDF document has been signed (probably with Adobe)?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, signature, crossplatform, adobe-acrobat

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I received a document, then forwarded it to other people who should be able to modify it. However digital signatures might prevent that.

How do I check if Adobe was used to sign the document? (without Adobe reader)

EDIT:
related questions:

[Verifying digital signature on PDF](https://askubuntu.com/q/1145849/382931)

[How can I validate a pdf's digital signature with evince?](https://askubuntu.com/q/226257/382931)

Answer (score 0):

You can use masterpdf. The last (free) [version](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/) can verify a signature. See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147379/how-do-i-digitally-sign-a-pdf-with-a-s-mime-certificate) answer.