# How to remove (adobe) digital signature from PDF

Tags: pdf, signature

This follows up my previous question: [How to check if PDF has been digitally signed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1250934/382931).

Just in doubt a document has been digitally signed (e.g. with Adobe), how to remove the signature?

In particular, does "print to file" remove it?

Answer (score 3):

If you've got ghostscript installed try:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%stdout% -c .setpdfwrite -f locked.pdf > unlocked.pdf
```

That would remove signature.
If the pdf file has a password, then add parameter:

```
-sPDFPassword=$PASS
```

...and password would be disabled.

Comment: Okay Ghostscript are quite cryptic for a newbie like, and the man page does not help. However the online doc helped me understanding that `-c` provides commands to execute and necessitates `-f` after in order to give input files.
I need a way to check that the signature was effectively removed though...

Comment: The version of GhostScript (9.50) that comes with Ubuntu 20.04 complains that “The .setpdfwrite operator has been deprecated and will be removed entirely in the next release of Ghostscript.” Removing `-c .setpdfwrite` seems to work fine for me; out of interest, why did you include it in your command?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong You can check the output PDF with `pdfsig unlocked.pdf` (from the `poppler-tools` package). It will print “File 'unlocked.pdf' does not contain any signatures” if the PDF is unsigned.

Comment: @Wolfgang this would be the answer to my linked question! Thanks! The package is `poppler-utils` for me. Does it work for Adobe signatures?